# How to build Spark 1.1.0 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to build Spark 1.1.0 on Windows 7 and I ran `sbt assembly` that failed with the following `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error:

```
...    
[warn] Merging 'parquet\schema\Type$Repetition$3.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'parquet\schema\Type$Repetition.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'parquet\schema\Type.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'parquet\schema\TypeConverter.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'parquet\schema\TypeVisitor.class' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'plugin.properties' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'plugin.xml' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Merging 'reference.conf' with strategy 'concat'
[warn] Merging 'rootdoc.txt' with strategy 'first'
[warn] Strategy 'concat' was applied to a file
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to 1723 files
[warn] Strategy 'first' was applied to 2713 files
[info] Assembly up to date: D:\app\spark\assembly\target\scala-2.10\spark-assembly-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar
[info] Packaging D:\app\spark\examples\target\scala-2.10\spark-examples-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar ...
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:196)
        at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:88)
        ...
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Ag
        ...
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:197)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$addString$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:327)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:320)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.addString(Traversable.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:105)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.mkString(Traversable.scala:105)
        at sbt.Package$.sourcesDebugString(Package.scala:111)
        at sbt.Package$$anonfun$makeJar$2.apply(Package.scala:106)
        at sbt.Package$$anonfun$makeJar$2.apply(Package.scala:106)
        at sbt.MultiLogger.log(MultiLogger.scala:31)
        at sbt.Logger$class.debug(Logger.scala:121)
        at sbt.AbstractLogger.debug(Logger.scala:11)
        at sbt.Package$.makeJar(Package.scala:106)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.sbtassembly$Plugin$Assembly$$makeJar$1(Plugin.scala:187)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Plugin.scala:226)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Plugin.scala:222)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$outputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:57)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$outputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:52)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.apply(Plugin.scala:230)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:373)
        at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:370)
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Jav
a heap space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I tried to add `-Xmx1024m` to `sbt.bat` file, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the logs it appears that you're trying to build `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` version from the sources.

> [info] Assembly up to date: D:\app\spark\assembly\target\scala-2.10\spark-assembly-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-hadoop1.0.4.jar

If you want to *use* Spark I'd highly recommend downloading a package for your operating system instead from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.

If you insist on building Spark from the sources yourself, you should consider changing the build tool from sbt to Apache Maven. Given [Building Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark#building-spark) on GitHub and [Building Spark with Maven](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-with-maven.html) in the Spark documentation it appears that they've already switched to Apache Maven as the build tool for end users.

Use Maven to build Spark and follow the guideline:

> You’ll need to configure Maven to use more memory than usual by
>   setting MAVEN_OPTS. We recommend the following settings:
>
> ```
> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"
> ```

It should also work with sbt, though. Use `SBT_OPTS` and start over.